# How can Rails ApplicationMailer be configured to use an API (or RestClient) instead of smtp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, actionmailer

Can Rails' ApplicationMailer (formerly ActionMailer) be configured to use REST API instead of SMTP?

In other words, replace

```
  self.smtp_settings = {
    :address => ENV['MAILER_URL'],
    :port => ENV['MAILER_PORT'],
    :domain => ENV['MAILER_DOMAIN'],
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => ENV['MAILER_USER'],
    :password => ENV['MAILER_PWD'],
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

perhaps with something like

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :rest_client  # JUST A MADE UP EXAMPLE

config.action_mailer.rest_client = {
  api_auth_header:{"Authorization" => "Bearer #{ENV['MY_REST_MAILER_API_KEY']}" ,
  api_endpoint: ENV['MY_REST_MAILER_API_URL']
}
```

I see a specific gem for Sendgrid and other ESPs where they provide a gem, but I'm looking for a general ActionMailer-to-Rest solution where I can specify an arbitrary api endpoint, etc and not be tied to a gem (or a provider who provides a gem) and still have the power of the templating etc that ActionMailer provides.

It's not impossible to skip the ActionMailer class entirely and just write a new mailer class that uses RestClient, in fact we've done that for certain special cases. But for normal emails its slower, more error prone, and definitely more work to manually deal with template rendering etc etc each time you simply want to create a new email type (customer_thank_you.html.haml, customer_welcome.html.haml, etc etc).

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this if you create a custom delivery_method for ActionMailer.

To do it, you'll need to:

1. Write a new class that responds to a couple methods
2. Register your delivery_method
3. Configure action_mailer to use it in your config

A scaffold of what it might look like in practice could be something like this:

```rb
# lib/rest_mail.rb
# ActionMailer will instantiate this class to send the email.
class RestMail

  # initialize is called with the settings provided from your config
  def initialize(settings)
    @settings = settings
  end

  # deliver! is the only other required method.  It is passed the mail object to send.
  # mail.encoded returns the email in the format needed to send it.  
  # Look at other mail delivery methods for inspiration (Mail::Sendmail, Mail::FileDelivery, Mail::SMTP, etc)
  def deliver!(mail)
    @client.post(url: @settings['url'], payload: mail.encoded)
  end

  def rest_client
    @client ||= MyRestClient.new(@settings)
  end
end

# config/initializers/custom_mailer_delivery_methods.rb
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :rest_mail, RestMail

# optionally, specify defaults with the optional hash as the last parameter:
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :rest_mail, RestMail, {url: 'http://mydefaulturl.com'}

# config/environments/application.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :rest_mail
config.action_mailer.rest_mail_settings = { url: 'https://example.com', ...}
```

Hope that gets you on the right track!  If you find that you created something useful, perhaps you can make a gem of it and share it back with the community :)

Comment: thats a pretty cool answer, thanks. will post back here if I get something working.

Comment: @jpw did it work for you?